# Search a specific string in Youtube application from my app

Tags: android, youtube

I have a button that when i tap on it i want to invoke Youtube app and search for predefined string(the search string is constant, i mean that Youtube app will display automatically the results).
I know that for searching a channel, we put

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/user/channel"))
```

But what about searching for a specific video (constant string)?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this Intent For Search on Youtube :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
 intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
 intent.putExtra("query", "Android");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Perfect answer! This is just what i wanted to know ;)! Thanks :). Accepted in 3 minutes :p.

Comment: working even now! really good its from 2012 can't believe!

Answer (score 1):

```
public void searchYt(String searchQuery) {
    Intent searchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    searchIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
    searchIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchQuery);
    startActivity(searchIntent);
  }
```

call this method and pass your string as argument searchYt("freecodecamp")