# Pass a string into YouTube search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to allow the user to push a new controller which opens up YouTube. What I want to do is pass a string directly into the YT search bar. The string is the title of the previous view controller. So for example, say the user is looking at the view for an exercise called "Straight Leg Raise", by tapping a UIButton, YT opens up in a new view controller, and "Straight Leg Raise" automatically goes into the YT search bar. In this example the URL format for the Youtube search is "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=straight+leg+raise". I just don't know enough about strings to do this. The question was asked and answered for Android ([Search a specific string in Youtube application from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860456/search-a-specific-string-in-youtube-application-from-my-app)) but I cannot find a similar answer for iOS. Thank you.

The code to open the YouTube web view:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"];
NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlrequest];
```

As far as getting the string from the previous view controller, that is part of what I can't figure out.

Comment: Update your question with the code you have that creates the YouTube URL. Also include the code that allows you to get the title from the previous view controller. From that, someone should be able to help you combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to URL encode the search string before you include it in the URL. You can do this by including [this category from Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string/3426140#3426140):

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString_ch {
    NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char * source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then, assuming that your previous view controller’s title is called `exercise`, you can do

```
NSString *youTubeUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%@", [exercise URLEncodedString_ch]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:youTubeUrl];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Web Inspector in Safari you can get the 'id' of youtube search bar. Say 'id' is YOU_TUBE_SEARCH_ID. The javascript for setting title in search box is,

```
var searchBar = document.getElementById('YOU_TUBE_SEARCH_ID');
searchBar.value = YOUR_SEARCH_TEXT;
```

You can run this script by UIWebView API,

```
NSString *script = [NSString stringWitFormat:@"document.getElementById('YOU_TUBE_SEARCH_ID').value = %@",YOUR_SEARCH_TEXT];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

See this link for using web inspector

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

Comment: The interpolated search text needs to be escaped and placed within quotes.